# How to merge two arrays of object without duplicates(using the object id) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I want to merge by the id of the object:

```
$object1->id = "1234"
$object2->id = "34553"
object3->id = "432"
array1 = [$object1,$object2]
array2 = [$object3,$object2]
```

My desired result:

```
array3 = [$object1,$object2,$object3]
```

I tried to follow these instructions that I found:

```
//both arrays will be merged including duplicates
$result = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );
//duplicate objects will be removed
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $result)));
//array is sorted on the bases of id
sort( $result );
```

But it did not work (its just returns a merged array with duplicates objects)

Comment: your cose works - https://eval.in/512582

Comment: Please don't try to fix Marge. She is perfect the way she is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry fixed it before I saw your comment, should I put her back

Comment: Yes, please revert Marge to her untainted pure state.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe that was a *joke* of sorts lol *Marge* is so cute and perfect, *just the way she is* lol Think what Homer would say.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

The merged arrays will be uniqued and sorted naturally using the sort flag `SORT_REGULAR`. `SORT_REGULAR` will also cause the array items to be compared without changing the types. This (once you correct all of your syntax errors) will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1234
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 34553
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 432
        )

)
```

Comment: Maybe it was not clear enough my objects are not in the same object class.
first is stdClass and the second class is contentClass(for the example ) .
I think that because its not the same type of class, the array_unique not helping here.  even that  they have exactly the same variables

Comment: That seems to be a new question @Bakalash, not part of this question. The class shouldn't matter because an object is an object.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $array3 = array_unique( array_merge( $array1, array2 ) );
```

`array_merge()` gets everything in one array
and to remove duplicates use `array_unique()`